# Unique identifier of wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I need a unique identifier for the wordpress site.

I was thinking to use  wp_user  but there can be many "john_smith".

Is there a system variable I can echo out?

Is there a variable that gives the URL of the instance?

PS I  have looked at the docs at https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description  but I know little about WordPress so its not intelligible to me

Comment: What do you mean by "unique identifier for the wordpress site"?

Comment: There are many wordpress sites on the web.   I ned to be able to tell one from anohter

Comment: Unique identifier: [This plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wpsniffer-wordpress-theme/kihhefcbenhkjgjhchanjfhhflaojldn) works on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you need this URL from your plugin that will be installed on WP websites. To get WP URL you can use [get_site_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_site_url/) function:

```
$url = get_site_url();
```

Things might get complicated on **multisite** installation because each site will have it's own URL, and WP 4.6 has new function for fetching sites so you  first need to check which function exists.

```
$urls = [];

// WordPress >= 4.6
if ( function_exists( 'get_sites' ) ) {
    $sites = get_sites();
    foreach ( $sites as $site ) {
        $urls[] = get_site_url( $site->blog_id );
    }
}

// WordPress < 4.6
if ( function_exists( 'wp_get_sites' ) ) {
    $sites = wp_get_sites();
    foreach ( $sites as $site ) {
        $urls[] = get_site_url( $site['blog_id'] );
    }
}
```